How to resolve problems installing netplan rpm
I am attempting to install netplan on Rocky 9.3 which has no direct internet connection.  So I am trying to install packages via rpm and if see a failed dependency find it and scp it to the PC (Intel PC running Rocky 9.3).
[user@localhost ~]$ rpm -i netplan-0.105-3.el9.x86_64.rpm 
warning: netplan-0.105-3.el9.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 3228467c: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
    netplan-default-backend is needed by netplan-0.105-3.el9.x86_64
    netplan-libs(x86-64) = 0.105-3.el9 is needed by netplan-0.105-3.el9.x86_64

So I then try to install netplan-libs:
[user@localhost ~]$ sudo rpm -i netplan-libs-0.105-3.el9.x86_64.rpm
warning: netplan-libs-0.105-3.el9.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 3228467c: NOKEY
    package netplan-libs-0.105-4.el8.x86_64 (which is newer than netplan-libs-0.105-3.el9.x86_64) is already installed
        file /usr/lib64/libnetplan.so.0.0 from install of netplan-libs-0.105-3.el9.x86_64 conflicts with file from package netplan-libs-0.105-4.el8.x86_64

Then I try to remove what I thought was the wrong netplan-libs as in:
[user@localhost ~]$ sudo rpm -e netplan-libs-0.105-4.el8.x86_64.rpm 
error: package netplan-libs-0.105-4.el8.x86_64.rpm is not installed

Then I try to verify netplan:
[user@localhost ~]$ sudo rpm -V netplan-0.105-3.el9.x86_64.rpm 
[sudo] password for user: 
warning: netplan-0.105-3.el9.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 3228467c: NOKEY
Unsatisfied dependencies for netplan-0.105-3.el9.x86_64:
    netplan-default-backend is needed by netplan-0.105-3.el9.x86_64
    netplan-libs(x86-64) = 0.105-3.el9 is needed by netplan-0.105-3.el9.x86_64
missing   a /usr/lib/.build-id/a0/424de64ac60e79c18b7576b8e659fbef189232
missing   a /usr/lib/.build-id/ea/c29b62d5d3489d3841c17fa80c2f9ee68d3180
missing     /usr/lib/netplan
missing     /usr/lib/netplan/generate
missing     /usr/lib/netplan/netplan-dbus
missing     /usr/lib/systemd/system-generators/netplan
missing     /usr/sbin/netplan
missing     /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/netplan
missing     /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/io.netplan.Netplan.service
missing     /usr/share/dbus-1/system.d/io.netplan.Netplan.conf
missing     /usr/share/doc/netplan
missing     /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples
missing   d /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/bonding.yaml
missing   d /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/bonding_router.yaml
missing   d /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/bridge.yaml
missing   d /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/bridge_vlan.yaml
missing   d /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/dhcp.yaml
missing   d /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/dhcp_wired8021x.yaml
missing   d /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/direct_connect_gateway.yaml
missing   d /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/direct_connect_gateway_ipv6.yaml
missing   d /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/infiniband.yaml
missing   d /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/ipv6_tunnel.yaml
missing   d /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/loopback_interface.yaml
missing   d /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/modem.yaml
missing   d /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/network_manager.yaml
missing   d /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/offload.yaml
missing   d /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/openvswitch.yaml
missing   d /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/route_metric.yaml
missing   d /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/source_routing.yaml
missing   d /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/sriov.yaml
missing   d /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/sriov_vlan.yaml
missing   d /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/static.yaml
missing   d /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/static_multiaddress.yaml
missing   d /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/static_singlenic_multiip_multigateway.yaml
missing   d /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/vlan.yaml
missing   d /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/vrf.yaml
missing   d /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/vxlan.yaml
missing   d /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/windows_dhcp_server.yaml
missing   d /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/wireguard.yaml
missing   d /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/wireless.yaml
missing   d /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/wpa_enterprise.yaml
missing   d /usr/share/doc/netplan/netplan.html
missing     /usr/share/licenses/netplan
missing   l /usr/share/licenses/netplan/COPYING
missing   d /usr/share/man/man5/netplan.5.gz
missing   d /usr/share/man/man8/netplan-apply.8.gz
missing   d /usr/share/man/man8/netplan-dbus.8.gz
missing   d /usr/share/man/man8/netplan-generate.8.gz
missing   d /usr/share/man/man8/netplan-get.8.gz
missing   d /usr/share/man/man8/netplan-set.8.gz
missing   d /usr/share/man/man8/netplan-try.8.gz
missing     /usr/share/netplan/netplan.script
missing     /usr/share/netplan/netplan/__init__.py
missing     /usr/share/netplan/netplan/_features.py
missing     /usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/__init__.py
missing     /usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/commands/__init__.py
missing     /usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/commands/apply.py
missing     /usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/commands/generate.py
missing     /usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/commands/get.py
missing     /usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/commands/info.py
missing     /usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/commands/ip.py
missing     /usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/commands/migrate.py
missing     /usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/commands/set.py
missing     /usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/commands/sriov_rebind.py
missing     /usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/commands/try_command.py
missing     /usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/core.py
missing     /usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/ovs.py
missing     /usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/sriov.py
missing     /usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/utils.py
missing     /usr/share/netplan/netplan/configmanager.py
missing     /usr/share/netplan/netplan/libnetplan.py
missing     /usr/share/netplan/netplan/terminal.py

How do I reliably install netplan.  I have downloaded what seem to be all the dependent files:
ls -l
-rwxr--r--. 1 user user  123581 Jun 24 14:39 netplan-0.105-3.el9.x86_64.rpm
-rwxr--r--. 1 user user    8221 Jun 24 15:21 netplan-default-backend-networkd-0.105-3.el9.noarch.rpm
-rwxr--r--. 1 user user    8273 Jun 24 15:35 netplan-default-backend-NetworkManager-0.105-3.el9.noarch.rpm
-rwxr--r--. 1 user user    8636 Jun 24 15:10 netplan-default-backend-NetworkManager-0.105-4.el8.noarch.rpm
-rwxr--r--. 1 user user  126265 Jun 24 15:40 netplan-libs-0.105-3.el9.x86_64.rpm
-rwxr--r--. 1 user user  123788 Jun 24 15:05 netplan-libs-0.105-4.el8.x86_64.rpm
-rwxr--r--. 1 user user   20996 Jun 24 15:13 NetworkManager-config-server-1.46.0-8.el9_4.noarch.rpm
-rwxr--r--. 1 user user   23050 Jun 24 15:15 python3-netifaces-0.10.6-15.el9.x86_64.rpm
-rwxr--r--. 1 user user  195078 Jun 24 15:18 python3-pyyaml-5.4.1-6.el9.x86_64.rpm

The most immediate problem I have is that I can't install netplan-libs-0.105-3.el9.x86_64.rpm because I get:
[user@localhost ~]$ sudo rpm -i netplan-libs-0.105-3.el9.x86_64.rpm 
[sudo] password for user: 
warning: netplan-libs-0.105-3.el9.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 3228467c: NOKEY
    package netplan-libs-0.105-4.el8.x86_64 (which is newer than netplan-libs-0.105-3.el9.x86_64) is already installed
    file /usr/lib64/libnetplan.so.0.0 from install of netplan-libs-0.105-3.el9.x86_64 conflicts with file from package netplan-libs-0.105-4.el8.x86_64

So I try to remove netplan-libs-0.105-4.el8.x86_64 like this:
[user@localhost ~]$ sudo rpm -e netplan-libs-0.105-4.el8.x86_64.rpm 
error: package netplan-libs-0.105-4.el8.x86_64.rpm is not installed

Can I manually remove /usr/lib64/libnetplan.so.0.0 ?  Or will that cause more problems?  What is the best way to fix this?

I would give a try to sudo rpm -e netplan-libs to uninstall the el8 ones, then install the el9 ones.
